# Adobe Illustrator | Edit subdivisions in 3D Revolve > Wireframe

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to edit the amount of subdivisions (or lines) in the adobe Revolve Wireframe tool?

With subdivisions I mean this. Fig. 1 is a close-up of Fig. 2
[image: image of the double lines]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## No.

Illustrator's 3D mesh is auto-generated and offers **zero** user control. You get whatever the app creates, and that's all.

The 3D effect in Illustrator has not been updated, for anything other than new version compatibility, in over 20 years. It's not meant to be *real* 3D functionality, but rather a stop-gap substitute. If you wish to control meshes, you need an *actual* 3D application.

Answer (score 1):

The 3D version of the wireframe is (as said already in an older answer) uneditable. If you planned to edit the 3D forms in this way, forget it. Illustrator isn't your tool. (see NOTE1)

**You can edit the 2D image of the wireframe** after you have applied Object > Expand Appearance, Object > Clipping Mask > Release  and as many times as needed Object > Ungroup.

Follow in the Layers panel how the disassembly progress. The Layers panel also provides a way to select separate parts which happen to be in the same place. At least the released clipping mask is surplus.

You can delete pieces of the expanded, unmasked and ungrouped image with the Shape Builder tool. Select all, hold the Alt key and click with the Shape Builder on an unwanted curve. It vanishes.

If there happens to be a duplicate under the curve (which happens often in this case) both will disappear, so check the structure in the layers panel by checking how many pieces actually are selected if you select by dragging over a line.

You can lock and hide pieces easily in the Layers panel if needed.

Combine curve segments to one closed area with the Shape Builder without pressing the Alt key.

Learn the tool options from the User's Guide. There are plenty of them.

You'll see soon that all curves have incredible many anchor points and they all are in irrational places - you would never put them there if you drew the same looking curve with the pen or used preset shapes such as the ellipse. The anchors are placed by the math equation solver which does not at all care your convenience. Object > Path > Simplify can reduce them. You decide how much change you allow as the cost of the simplifying.

You do not need simplifying if you are not going to do own form variations.

NOTE1: It's not at all clear that a real 3D modelling program allows you to edit a curve in a wireframe of a revolved piece. If you move a node of a curve it will be in contradiction with the fact it was revolved. The wireframe is calculated only to visualize the geometry, the 3D geometry hasn't backward dependency on those curves except in case there's a way to convert the revolution surface to a surface which is lofted between the wireframe curves, say lofted between the circles and using the vertical curves as spines. I guess the only actual editables are the revolved curve and the axis.

I guess programs based on polygon surface modelling do not have that limitation. Maybe a 3D modelling specialist could give some useful information (=no guesses). Most of us in GDSE make layouts and draw & mangle 2D images.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that the base primitive is a bezier curve. It turns out that because its not rational it makes perspective divide a bit hard to do... Had the primitive been a rational bezier, rational b-spline or a nurb spline then you probably would have had 3D years ago. Simply a rational spline wouldnt need those extra points. You know the same reason circles in illustrator are never actually circles.

Comment: @joojaa can you possibly comment the inserted part NOTE1. It's only some guesses, knowledge is welcome.

Comment: Depends on whether the application is a direct or indirect modeler.

Comment: Nice answer, but can you edit the words highlighted in "except in **care** there's a way to convert the revolution to a **loft** between the wireframe curves" because it makes no sense. I'd do it for you but I've no idea what you are trying to say. Thanks

Comment: @BillyKerr it's maybe fixed now.

Comment: @user287001 - still a problem "lofted" doesn't make sense either. Sorry.

Comment: Loft isn't a well descriptive natural language word, not at least as a verb (a kind of lifting) , it's an ancient CAD term  https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-0A041818-2E32-4212-A3D8-CE0361C3D229-htm.html#:~:text=Creates%20a%203D%20solid%20or,space%20between%20several%20cross%20sections.&text=The%20cross%20sections%20define%20the,can%20also%20be%20edge%20subobjects.

Comment: @user287001 - OK, but then it would be better to write something like "use a LOFT command".  "Lofted" is already a word in English, and it's totally confusing to use it in this context. It means throwing something - launching a projectile, not lifting something.

Comment: Those of us who live far behind the horizon and speak only some tribal language do not always remember that people who live in modern metropolies can also have quite rotten English language skills https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/video/youtube/lesson/144765-courseId-100329.html

Comment: (continued) I guess the term loft in this meaning is created by Autodesk but for us (=foreigners) it looks like Shakespeare could have used it as well. We also use dictionaries which look like their content is somehow established and reliable https://i.stack.imgur.com/05cmR.png